# undefined method `update_attributes' for #

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, model-view-controller

I get this error

```
NoMethodError in UsersController#update
undefined method `update_attributes' for #<User id: 1, 
first_name: "Bob", last_name: "Cool", 
created_at: "2021-03-10 06:06:13.238325000 +0000", 
updated_at: "2021-03-10 06:06:13.238325000 +0000">
```

I want to edit the user information with the form like this ;

[image]

This is my `users_controller.rb` ;

```rb
before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update]

def update
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      redirect_to edit_user_path(@user), 
      error: @user.errors.full_messages.join(', ')
    end
  end

private
  def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name)
  end
```

This is my `edit.html.rb`

```rb
<p>
  <%= form_with model: @user, url: user_path(id: @user.id), method: :put, local: true do |form| %>
    <%= render 'form', form: form %>
  <% end %>
</p>
```

This is my `_form.html.erb`

```rb
<%= form.label 'First Name: '%>
<%= form.text_field 'first_name' %>
<br/>
<%= form.label 'Last Name: '%>
<%= form.text_field 'last_name' %>
<br/>
<%= form.submit 'Submit' %>
```

I try to look at `@user`, but when it came to `update_attributes`, it gives this error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> This method is deprecated or moved on the latest stable version.

[update_attributes](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_attributes) is already
been depreated.

You could use [update](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update) instead:

```rb
@user.update(user_params)
```

Comment: @AmirulAsyraf you should mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

The method `update_attributes(params)` is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. you have to use `update(params)` instead.
So your code would look like this:

```
def update
  if @user.update(user_params)
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    redirect_to edit_user_path(@user), 
    error: @user.errors.full_messages.join(', ')
  end
end
```